# POSTFIX and PREFIX increment/decrement precedence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

I've been coding for years and suddenly stuck to some simple thing about operators precedence in case of increment/decrement operators.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence
the *postfix* increment/decrement has higher priority than the *prefix* one.
So, I expect that in expression

```
x = --a  + a++;
```

the *increment* will be calculated first and only after that the *decrement*.
But, in tests this expression calculates left-to-right like that operators have the same priority. And as result 
`a=1;x = --a + a++`  equals to 0 instead of 2.

Ok. Assuming that prefix/postfix operators have the same precedence, I try to reorder it with  parentheses:

```
a=1;x = --a  + ( a++ )
```

But again, the result will be 0 and not 2 as I expected.

Can someone explain that please? why parentheses here do not affect anything? How can I see that postfix has higher precedence than prefix?

Comment: Oh you're right; sorry I read it incorrectly. However that doesn't matter for the particular expression you posted; the expression is still interpreted as `(--a)+(a++)` and the left side is still evaluated first.

Comment: Yep, I see how it is evaluated, And do not understand why. What's the point in difference of precedence?

Comment: I *think* the precedence difference is to account for the fact that box 16 operators are right-to-left, but that wouldn't work with (for example) `-a++` which should be the negative of the value of `a`. *edit* wait no that doesn't make sense; I don't know I guess, the JavaScript (and C) expression syntax is really complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence is not the same thing as evaluation order.

Operator precedence tells you that

```
f() + g() * h()
```

is parsed as

```
f() + (g() * h())
```

(because `*` has higher precedence than `+`), but not which function is called first. That is controlled by evaluation order, which in JavaScript is always left-to-right.

Parentheses only override precedence (i.e. they affect how subexpressions are grouped), not order of evaluation:

```
(f() + g()) * h()
```

performs addition before multiplication, but in all cases `f` is called first and `h` last.

In your example

```
--a + a++
```

the relative precedence of prefix `--` and postfix `++` doesn't matter because they're not attached to the same operand. Infix `+` has much lower precedence, so this expression parses as

```
(--a) + (a++)
```

As always, JS expressions are evaluated from left to right, so `--a` is done first.

If you had written

```
--a++
```

that would have been parsed as

```
--(a++)
```

(and not `(--a)++`) because postfix `++` has higher precedence, but the difference doesn't matter here because either version is an error: You can't increment/decrement the result of another increment/decrement operation.

However, in the [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) you can see that all prefix operators have the same precedence, so we can show an alternative:

```
// ! has the same precedence as prefix ++
!a++
```

is valid code because it parses as `!(a++)` due to postfix `++` having higher precedence than `!`. If it didn't, it would be interpreted as `(!a)++`, which is an error.

Comment: Well, it seems that I have confused the concepts of "operator precedence" and "evaluation order". Did I get you right that all ++ -- are evaluated simply left-to-right before applying precedence rules?

Answer (score 3):

In the expression, evaluation proceeds like this:

1. `--a` is evaluated. The variable `a` is decremented, and the value of `--a` is therefore `0`.
2. `a++` is evaluated. The value of `a` is obtained, and *then* `a` is incremented. The value of `a++` is therefore `0`.
3. The `+` operation is performed, and the result is `0`.
4. The final value of `a` is `1`.

Because `--a` and `a++` are on either side of the lower-precedence `+` operator, the difference in precedence between pre-decrement and post-increment doesn't matter; the `+` operator evaluates the left-hand subexpression before it evaluates the right-hand subexpression.

Comment: That all was clear. The main questions was: why parentheses here do not affect anything and How can I see that postfix has higher precedence than prefix? I'm still in confusion

Comment: @RomanAzarov I don't think it's possible to see that post-increment has higher precedence than pre-decrement because you cannot use both in the same subexpression. In other words, `--a++` is a syntax error because those operators require the operand to be an *l-value*, something that can be on the left side of `=`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it strange, but looks like increment/decrement behaves in expressions like a function call, not like an operator.
I could not find any documentation regarding order of function evaluations in expression, but looks like it ignores any precedence rules. So strange expression like that:

```
console.log(1) +  console.log(2)* ( console.log(3)  + console.log(4))
```

will show 1234 in console. That the only explanation I could found why parentheses do not affect to order of evaluation of dec/inc in expressions